# Destructing array of objects without assigning each a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, destructuring

I've looked in stack, but I couldn't find the answer to my question, if It's a duplicate I'm really sorry.

I have an array of objects:

```
export const people = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Thom"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bob"
  }
];
```

I am importing this file:

```
import {people} from '../Person';
```

I'm assigning the state:

```
  state = {
        peopleData: people
    }
```

And I'm trying to destruct this array like this, but unfortunately, I'm not allowed to do that:

```
const{people} = this.state.peopleData;
```

What is the reason that I'm not able to iterate with `map` function over my people?

```
{people.map(person=> (<Person key={person.id} personInfo={person}/>))}
```

I can do like that of course, but I don't want to, because If I would need to iterate couple more times I would need always to write the same code `this.state.peopleData`...:

```
{  
 this.state.peopleData.map(person=> (<Person key={person.id} personInfo={person}/>
))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assigning the state:
>
> ```js
> state = {
>    peopleData: people
> }
> ```
>
> And I'm trying to destruct this array like this, but unfortunately, I'm not allowed to do that:
>
> ```js
> const{people} = this.state.peopleData;
> ```

It would be either this, without destructuring:

```js
const people = this.state.peopleData;
```

or this with destructuring:

```js
const {peopleData: people} = this.state;
```

...which says "take the value of the property `peopleData` from `this.state` and put it into the constant `people`.

Comment: *(Gah! Editing error. If you see `.peopleData` at the end of the last example above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: But this.state.peopleData is an array, how can I assign it to const people?

Comment: @T.Jony - It doesn't matter that it's an array. The above **does** assign it to the const `people`. Is your goal to assign the individual entries from the array to variables? (But no, that wouldn't make sense, because you're using `map`, so you want it to be the array...)

Comment: No, it's not. I just want to pass my object properties to another component. Big thanks!

Comment: @T.Jony - Happy to help! So that did sort it out?

Comment: Yes, I'll make this as an answer. Is there any difference between your two examples how to assign peopleData to a const people? Or I can use both of them freely?

Comment: @T.Jony - Nope, no difference, they do exactly the same thing, just with different syntax, so whatever works! :-) That wouldn't *quite* be true if we were doing iterable destructuring with `[]` rather than object destructuring with `{}` (there's a slight difference between `const [a] = someArray;` and `const a = someArray[0];`, but this is object destructuring, so it's exactly the same. (FWIW, I go into destructuring in some depth in my new book -- see my profile if you want details.) Happy coding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217242/discussion-between-t-jony-and-t-j-crowder).